# UIAutomation with custom navigationbar

Tags: javascript, automation, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, xcode5

I don't have the standard NavigationController nor a scrollView, TableView ....

Once the application finish launching and after the `appDelegate`,  it goes to `UIViewController` object.

On the view of this viewController, I have `UITextField`. If I want to write to this text filed. Through `UIAutomation JavaScript`
among many other options I have tried the following and still had no luck:

`var name = "Test Text";
var textField  = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().textFields()[0];
textField.setValue(name);`

after `mainWindow()` how do I be able to accesses or get a hold of my `UIViewController` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the hierarchy of the user interface elements you can insert the command `UIATarget.localTarget().logElementTree();` Studying the output of this command you will be able to guess the correct expression. In some cases you need to wait until every item is created (for example with `UIATarget.localTarget().delay(1);`) before logging.

An other oportunity to get the right answer is to record with Instuments as you fill this textfield (manualy) and check the generated code.